# Airflow - send slack notification with attachments and result as custom message

Tags: python, notifications, airflow, slack

I am using airflow to execute my machine learning model which generates an image file and a score as output. Also I am using slack to notify the DAG success or failure.
I want to send the generated image file as attachment and the score as message with the slack notification.

My code:
**send_slack_notification.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, division

import os

from   airflow.contrib.operators.slack_webhook_operator \
                            import SlackWebhookOperator


class SlackAlert(object):
"""
Inherit this class and specify _webhook_token to send alert to a different channel
"""
_webhook_token = "xxxxxxxxx"


def send_slack_alert(self, context):
    """
    Args:
        slack_con_id (Enum): SlackAlertEnum.AdTech or SlackAlertEnum.Others
    """
    slack_webhook_token = self._webhook_token

    slack_msg = """
            :white_check_mark: Task Success!! :partying_face: 
            *Task*: {task}  
            *Dag*: {dag} 
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
            *Log Url*: {log_url} 
    """.format(
        task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
        dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
        exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
        log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url.replace('localhost:8080', os.environ.get('PUBLIC_IP', '')),
    )
    success_alert = SlackWebhookOperator(
        task_id='slack_test',
        http_conn_id='slack',
        webhook_token=slack_webhook_token,
        message=slack_msg,
        username='airflow')
    return success_alert.execute(context=context)


 # TODO: Remove this line once all jobs are moved to new airflow instances managed by AWS
 #send_failure_alert = SlackAlert().send_failure_alert
 send_slack_alert = SlackAlert().send_slack_alert
```

Also my **DAG code**:

```
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from   airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
#from   data_science.anomaly_detection.scripts.anomaly_detection_live_run import flag_anomaly
from   data_science.anomaly_detection.pipeline.ad_flagging_anomaly_live import flag_anomaly
from   data_science.send_slack_alert import SlackAlertDataScience

def __flag_anomaly(ds, **kwargs):
    result = flag_anomaly()
    logging.info(result)    

dag = DAG('anomaly-infra-test',
      description='Flagging Anomaly detection data hourly',
      schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
      on_failure_callback=SlackAlertDataScience().send_slack_alert,
      on_success_callback=SlackAlertDataScience().send_success_alert,
      start_date=datetime(2022,1,1),
      catchup=False,
      max_active_runs=1,
      tags=["DataScience"]
      )


anomaly_detection_data_operator = PythonOperator(task_id='hourly_anomaly_detection_data_task',
                                             python_callable=__flag_anomaly,
                                             dag=dag,
                                             provide_context=True)
anomaly_detection_data_operator
```

For now, I am getting success and failure notifications on my slack channel.

I have tried to read some other related questions but I was not able to figure out how to pass the file as attachment and generated score as slack notification message in the line **on_success_callback=SlackAlertDataScience().send_success_alert,** of DAG code.

I have started using airflow recently, so any help is appreciated.